# Quick sort created by Lua does not work correctly

Tags: algorithm, lua, quicksort

I am a person who has been studying Lua recently. I am writing a QuickSort in Lua. I have translated the quick sort code that I wrote in Go language into Lua, and the code is below. Table.slice funcion defines the function used when making recursive calls in QuickSort.

```
function table.slice(tbl, first, last, step)
    local sliced = {}

    for i = first , last , step  do
        sliced[#sliced+1] = tbl[i]
    end

    return sliced
end

function quickSort(array)
    if #array < 2 then 
        return array
    end

    local left = 1
    local right =  #array
    local pivot = math.random( 1, #array )

    array[pivot], array[right] = array[right], array[pivot]

    for i = 1, #array do
        if array[i] > array[right] then
            array[left], array[i] = array[i], array[left]

            left = left + 1
        end
    end

    array[left], array[right] = array[right], array[left]

    a = table.slice(array,1,left-1,1)
    b = table.slice(array,left+1,#array,1)
    quickSort(a)
    quickSort(b)

    return array
end
```

I initially thought that I made a mistake about Lua's table index starting at 1, but I could not tell where I was wrong. Could you tell me where I was wrong? Thank you.

Comment: You've forgotten to write sorted arrays `a` and `b` back to big array `array`.  In Go a slice is a reference to source array.  In Lua your "slice" is just a new copy (a separate array) which has no connection with its source.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I modified it by modifying the table directly by passing a range value as a parameter, and it works correctly. Thank you.

Comment: `table.sort` already implements QuickSort...

Comment: I know. Thank you, I am just studying Lua :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the code by modifying the given table directly by passing the range value as a parameter along with the comment, and posting the code for quick sort.

```
function quickSort(array, le, ri)
    if ri-le < 1 then 
        return array
    end

    local left = le
    local right =  ri
    local pivot = math.random( le, ri )

    array[pivot], array[right] = array[right], array[pivot]

    for i = le, ri do
        if array[i] > array[right] then
            array[left], array[i] = array[i], array[left]

            left = left + 1
        end
    end

    array[left], array[right] = array[right], array[left]

    quickSort(array, 1, left-1)
    quickSort(array, left +1, ri)

    return array
end
```